# C# Removing attribute XML

Tags: c#, xml

I am trying to remove some specified attributed from the XML file sample code was below.    string[] szNodeList is the array list so node contains name in string array will be removed ans save again

Any help will be appreciated.

```
        var doc = new System.Xml.XmlDocument();
        doc.Load("attrs.xml");
        var root = doc.DocumentElement;
        string[] szNodeList = new string[]  { "titleTextColor"
        ,"isLightTheme"
        ,"showText"
                    };
        foreach (System.Xml.XmlElement  child in root )
        {
            foreach (string sz in szNodeList)
            {
                root.RemoveAttribute(sz);
                //if (child.Attributes[sz] != null)
                //{
                //    child.Attributes.Remove(child.Attributes[sz]);
                //}
            }
        }

        doc.Save("build.xml");

    XML CODE

  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <resources>
    <attr name="cropImageStyle" format="reference" />
    <attr name="drawerArrowStyle" format="reference" />
    <attr name="height" format="dimension" />
    <attr name="isLightTheme" format="boolean" />
    <attr name="title" format="string" />
    <attr name="navigationMode">
      <enum name="listMode" value="1" />
      <enum name="normal" value="0" />
      <enum name="tabMode" value="2" />
    </attr>

  </resources>
```

But saving as original file without changes i thing remove is not working.

Comment: You need to tell us *specifically* what didn't work.

Comment: Edited now ....

Comment: Out of interest, would you be happy to use LINQ to XML instead of XmlDocument? That generally makes things significantly simpler.

Comment: can you specify exactly which attributes are you removing and what is saved instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
doc
    // select all `resources/attr` node
    .SelectNodes("resources/attr")
    .Cast<XmlNode>()
    // that contains the `name` attribute whose value is in `szNodeList`
    .Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.Attributes["name"]?.Value) && szNodeList.Contains(x.Attributes["name"].Value))
    .ToList()
    // and, remove them from their parent
    .ForEach(x => x.ParentNode.RemoveChild(x));
```

Answer (score 1):

One of the problems here is terminology. You're not trying to remove *attributes*, as I understand it - you're trying to remove whole *elements*, based on the value of the `name` attribute.

If you can possibly use LINQ to XML for this, I would do so. It generally makes working with XML a lot easier. Here's a complete program to do what you want:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml.Linq;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var namesToRemove = new[]
        { 
            "titleTextColor",
            "isLightTheme",
            "showText"
        };
        XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("test.xml");
        // For all the elements directly under the document root...
        doc.Root.Elements()
            // Where the array contains the value of the "name" attribute...
            .Where(x => namesToRemove.Contains((string) x.Attribute("name")))
            // Remove them from the document
            .Remove();
        doc.Save("output.xml");
    }
}
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
  <attr name="cropImageStyle" format="reference" />
  <attr name="drawerArrowStyle" format="reference" />
  <attr name="height" format="dimension" />
  <attr name="title" format="string" />
  <attr name="navigationMode">
    <enum name="listMode" value="1" />
    <enum name="normal" value="0" />
    <enum name="tabMode" value="2" />
  </attr>
</resources>
```